# Primefaces Modify datatable which has data from database

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to modify my datatable which display data from mysql database:

```
                <p:dataTable id="contrats" var="contrat" value="${contrat.getContratFromDataBase()}" rowKey="#{contrat.idContrat}"
                 selection="#{tabBeanContrat.contratTab}" editable="true" editMode="cell" >
                 <p:column selectionMode="multiple"  style="width:2%" /> 

                    <p:column headerText="Ref Propale">
                                <p:cellEditor> 
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText id="refPropale" value="#{contrat.refPropale}" ></h:outputText></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInputrefPropale" value="#{contrat.refPropale}"/></f:facet>                      
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Ref Commande">
                            <p:cellEditor> 
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{contrat.refCommande}"></h:outputText></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInputrefCommande" value="#{contrat.refCommande}"/></f:facet> 
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Description">
                                <p:cellEditor> 
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{contrat.description}"></h:outputText></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInputdescription" value="#{contrat.description}"/></f:facet> 
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Total jh vendus">
                            <p:cellEditor> 
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{contrat.chargeVendue}"></h:outputText></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInputchargeVendue" value="#{contrat.chargeVendue}"/></f:facet> 
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Budget (€HT)">
                            <p:cellEditor> 
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{contrat.budget}"></h:outputText></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInputbudget" value="#{contrat.budget}"/></f:facet> 
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Statut">
                            <p:cellEditor> 
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{contrat.statut}"></h:outputText></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInputstatut" value="#{contrat.statut}"/></f:facet> 
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
```

The method getContratFromDataBase() retrieve data from a table in my msql database. 
So the problem is when I want to modify a cell, the new value is not taken into account (the new value is not displayed) because  I use value="${contrat.getContratFromDataBase()}" so it will always displayed the values of the database. Does anyone have an idea to solve my problem.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The trick is on your managed bean getContractsFromDataBase() method.
The method should not ask database each time the property is called.

- Consider using a new method "getContracts" that return a list of Contract objects.
- The list must be filled (using getContractsFromDataBase) at PostConstruct time or at the first call of getContracts.
- Check that the bean scope is adapted to your needs
- set p:dataTable value="${yourbean.contracts}" ...

*Example:*

```
  ArrayList<Contract> contracts = null;
  Public List<Contract> getContracts {
    if (contracts == null)
      contracts = getContractsFromDatabase();
    return contracts;
  }
```

**EDIT:**

You want to edit values within the datatable (editable="true" editMode="cell"), so add an ajax event to trigger cell changes:

```
 <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{tabBeanContrat.onCellEdit}" />
```

And add the event on your managed bean *tabBeanContrat*.

```
 public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {  
        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();  
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();  
        if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {  
            // apply changes here (call method to update DB)
        }  
    }
```

Comment: I tried but it dont display my data from my DB because after that i want to modify some values of my datatable with an update query.

Comment: Once loaded in the ArrayList, the Contract objects can be modified the way you want as these objects are stored in memory. You want the DataTable cells to be editable, so you need to add a "onCellEdit" method on your managed bean (ajax triggered on cell change). See http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableCellEditing.jsf

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for your answer,

to be more precise here is my tabBeanContrat bean :

```
            public static ArrayList<Contrat> getContratFromDB() {
            try {

                PreparedStatement ps = conec.prepareStatement("select * from contrats");
                ArrayList<Contrat> al = new ArrayList<Contrat>();
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                boolean found = false;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Contrat c = new Contrat();
                    c.setRefPropale(rs.getString("RefPropale"));
                    c.setRefCommande(rs.getString("RefCommande"));
                    c.setDescription(rs.getString("Description"));
                    c.setChargeVendue(rs.getDouble("ChargeVendue"));
                    c.setBudget(rs.getFloat("Budget"));
                    c.setStatut(rs.getString("StatutCharge"));     

                    al.add(c);
                    found = true;
                }
                rs.close();
                if (found) {
                    return al;
                } else {
                    return null; // no entires found
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error In getContratFromDB() -->" + e.getMessage());
                return (null);
            }
        }
```

Then in my Contrat class  i have this method :

```
   public ArrayList<Contrat> getContratFromDataBase() {
    return TabBeanContrat.getContratFromDB();
}
```

So i have to put this in my tabBeanContrat @ManagedBean(name = "tabBeanContrat"):

```
   private List<Contrat> contrats = new ArrayList<Contrat>();

    public List<Contrat> getContrats() {            
            if (contrats == null)
              contrats = getContratFromDB();
            return contrats;            
    }
```

Finnaly i have to change value of my datatable from `value="${contrat.getContratFromDataBase()}"` to `value="${tabBeanContrat.contrats}"`